# why am I getting strange array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm doing something wrong here because I'm getting the following strange array

```
 $salaryarray=[''];
 $eduarray= array();

 $profiles = Profile::all();
     foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
         array_push($salaryarray, $profile['salrange']);
         echo '<br>';
         print_r($salaryarray);
         echo count($salaryarray);
         echo '<br>';
         echo $salaryarray[1];
      }
```

Here is my output. The values are correct but I don't understand the first element `$salaryarray[0]`. First I thought it was an array of arrays but the count() is 4

```
( [0] => [1] => 70 [2] => 150 [3] => 34 )
```

4

70

Comment: so, what is the exact question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you declared array as `$salaryarray=['']` and first element is an empty string use

```
$salaryarray = [];
```

instead

Comment: or even better ``$salaryarray = array()`` for the consistency